# How does iCloud Photos for Windows "sync" photos and videos?

Tags: icloud, windows, pc

Here are some possible options I can think of:

- **One-way cumulative copy from iCloud to My PC.** Example: Files added to iCloud will be added to My PC but Files deleted from iCloud, will remain on My PC. This can either happen in near real time or on demand.
- **One-way mirror of iCloud maintained on My PC.** Example: If files are added or deleted from iCloud, they will be added or deleted from My PC. This assumes iCloud as the master of record for all files generated by connected Apple devices.
- **Two-way mirror between iCloud and My PC.** Example: If files are added or deleted from iCloud, they will be added or deleted from My PC and vice-versa. This assumes the acting system as the master of record. This is a more advanced option and may require that changes made at each side be either (1) queued/tracked so they can later be applied, or (2) applied in real time in an ordered fashion.
- **None of the above.**

I would at least expect that:

- One copy of each file is maintained on My PC. Right now, clicking "Download photos and videos" on iCloud Photos more than once seems to create duplicate files.
- The association between files and their albums be retained when files are transferred to My PC (maybe using a similar directory structure).
- The software gives me the option to pause, stop, continue, or cancel the "sync" process.

Any ideas on how iCloud Photos for Windows really "sync" our photos and videos to our PCs?